# uml database two players battles history struxture

Tags: sql, database

Let's say I have two tables: `user` and `battle`

The first contains a `player_id` as primary key and some other informations. The second contains a `battle_id` as primary ket, the `1st_player_id` and `2nd_player_id` as foreign keys and the result of the battle (no matter the type).

Let's assume my game became more viral than Covid, and I have tons of battles to store.

If a user wants to get an history of the battles he played, I'll have to search for his `player_id` in the whole `battle` table, in both `1st_player_id` and `2nd_player_id` attributes.
Maybe I can add an attribute in the `user` table, that stores an array of `match_id`. That would make the search faster, but I think it's a bit redundant.

Is there a better / more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take the player id columns out of the battle table and create an intersection table between player and battle

**Update**

The PK would be player + battle.

For every battle you would have 2 records in the intersection table, 1 for player 1 and 1 for player 2

In any given battle there is no logic difference between the 2 players (either could be "player 1") so you should be modelling both identically.

If there is any information that you want to hold that is specific to the player-battle combination you can hold it in the intersection table record